# Python SystemError: bad BUILD_CONST_KEY_MAP keys argument

Tags: python, dictionary, key, python-3.10, pycord

I have some code running in python3.10 and about 80% of the time I get this error

```
SystemError: bad BUILD_CONST_KEY_MAP keys argument
```

the error is thrown on a line which sets a value in a map

```
a_map= defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: {}))
a_map[key1][key2] = {...}
```

The project is fairly large so its hard to share code, although the main issue is that when I place a breakpoint on the line that sets the value in the map (this is the line which the backtrace points to is the cause), no error is thrown. The error only seems to occur when no breakpoint is set.

I am not really sure how to debug this any further, I have put prints in the code to output the map and keys and everything looks valid and fine.

Any pointers on what to check or how to gather more debug information?

Comment: Are you using any installed C extensions or modifying bytecode in any way? If not, consider paring this down to a minimal reproducable example and reporting to bugs.python.org.

Comment: In looking through your codebase and the installed extension modules, I'd be on particular lookout for code that modifies the `co_consts` of a python code object like `some_function.__code__ = some_function.__code__.replace(co_consts=...)` or something like that.

Comment: nope not using any C extensions that i know of. I am not doing anything funky with the map other than storing some strings, ints and doubles in there. Its really hard to make a minimal reproducible example since this is transient. Even without breakpoints like 20-30% of the time everything works fine

Comment: I deffinely dont have any code that i wrote which uses ```__code__ ```. The only major library this is all running under is pycord(https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord), I can look through to see if they are using that anywhere. 

But none of my code does anything funky like that

Comment: You could do a loop where you repeatedly construct a mapping like that and insert randomized (e.g. `random.random()`) data of the same types. If the same input gives different results at different times, maybe it could depend on string hash randomization as well, so you could try setting PYTHONHASHSEED=0 to get consistent results.

Comment: I guess another thing would be to look for places in your code where the BUILD_CONSTANT_KEY_MAP opcode is used (namely dictionary literals with keys that are integers or strings or floats or tuples of these) . This seems like might be a bug in Python, so if you can figure out a small reproducer, reporting to bugs.python.org would be the way to go. You could also check whether this affects newer/older python versions.

Comment: Another helpful piece of information would be the output of `import dis; dis.dis(the_function_that_crashes)`

Comment: ok will have to give this a try, I am using const keys a bunch in various spots, In fact I am parsing a bunch of these keys out of a json file. I will try and get a minimal reproducible example with the PYTHONHASHSEED=0


This crash is in the mainloop of a thread i start up. Do you mean run ```dis.dis``` on the mainloop? Because the crash is on the write into the map

Comment: Note that `{x: y, z: w}` won't use BUILD_CONST_KEY_MAP, but something like `{0: x, "a": bar() }` will -- the keys need to be literals, not variables loaded from somewhere, unless you're doing strange things with eval() or exec()

Comment: Try running dis.dis on the function containing the write to the map.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243637/discussion-between-lufthansa747-and-dennis).